# Lining up results in email from php script?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to figure out how to make all my results line up together evenly in the email from my php script.

I would like it to look like this:

```
Registry No.:      12345X
First Name:        Erik
Last Name:         Peterson



$Body = "";
$Body .= "Registry No.: ";
$Body .= $reg;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "First Name: ";
$Body .= $first_name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Last Name: ";
$Body .= $last_name;
```

Comment: what about html email and then use a table.

Comment: I only need two columns.  Is it really necessary?  How about spaces?

Comment: sure you can, but depending on font usage at the other end, you cant be sure it will line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP_EOL for line break. i use it for sending mails to insert line breaks. and it works for me.

and regarding the formatting you can either use html table or use some spacing.

**Update :**

sending HTML mail through PHP is exact same mail function. for example/

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

however you need to add the content/type in the header telling the mail client that it is html email

add this in your `$headers`

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and now you can append some html code to your $body variable for example.

```
$body = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Registry No.:</td>
        <td>$reg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td>$first_name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td>$last_name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
";
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: NEVER MADE ATABLE FOR EMAIL.  ANY EXAMPLES OUT THERE YOU CAN SHOW ME?

Comment: I've been trying it and it does not work...  Do i still use $Body  I want to keep it simple.

Comment: check out my updated answer. if you need extra spacing between the column then define the column width `<td width='100'>`